# Attaching SkyDrive files to Hotmail emails

Tags: outlook.com, attachment, onedrive

I love SkyDrive, but find it frustrating when I want to attach a file that's on my SkyDrive to a new Hotmail message. I have to download the SkyDrive file to my computer and then attach the file to the email.

Is there a way to "cut out the middle man" and just attach the file directly from SkyDrive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this.

What you can do is share the document or file you would otherwise send as an attachment.

1. Tick the checkbox next to the document filename
2. Click the **Share** link on the sidebar

From the Share dialog that pops up with various options, you can share directly with another person by emailing them.

Or you can click **Get a link** and select one of the options available:

- View only
- View and edit
- Make it public!

Then include the link in the body of your email.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst the question is specifically about Hotmail/SkyDrive, it may be worth noting that Google have now come up with a way of doing this with Gmail/Google Drive. All it seems to do, mind you, is help you share the document correctly with the people you're emailing to - it still doesn't actually attach it to the email from what I can see. Here's the [announcement](http://gmailblog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/gmail-and-drive-new-way-to-send-files.html).

Answer (score 1):

This at least cuts out the step of having to download the file as its already there.

[Download Microsoft SkyDrive](https://apps.live.com/skydrive/app/9a65e47d-606a-4816-a246-90f54bf7a3ea) - the following text was taken from the download page

> SkyDrive for Windows is the easiest way to access your SkyDrive from
>   your PC. When you install SkyDrive, a SkyDrive folder is created on
>   your PC. Everything that you put in this folder is automatically kept
>   in sync between your computers (PC or Mac) and SkyDrive.com, so you
>   can get to your latest files from virtually anywhere. Whenever you
>   add, change or delete files in one location, all of the other
>   locations will be updated.